# Fun examples relating to Hopf surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

A Hopf surface is a compact complex surface whose universal cover is complex analytically isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$. I would like to know whether anyone has any of the following examples:

(i) A non-compact complex surface whose universal cover is complex analytically isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

(ii) A compact complex surface whose universal cover is smoothly isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{ 0  \}$, but not complex analytically isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb C^2 \setminus \{0\}$ a silly example of (i)?  (Also, `\backslash` doesn't space well:  $\mathbb C^2 \backslash \{0\}$.  Prefer `\setminus`:  $\mathbb C^2 \setminus \{0\}$.  I have edited accordingly.)

Comment: Only marginally less silly: take a cyclic group acting linearly and freely on  $C^2 \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @DannyRuberman Thank you, but now the question remains: Can we find non-silly examples?

Comment: Look at Di Scala, Kasuya, Zuddas, Non-Kahler complex structures on $R^4$. These complex structures have embedded elliptic curves, so they won't be isomorphic to $\Bbb C^2 \setminus 0$ after removing a point. However, I doubt that they have compact quotients.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**(ii)** I would like to prove that there are no complex surfaces that satisfy (ii).

Indeed, suppose that the universal cover $\widetilde X$ of a complex surface $X$ is diffemorphic to $\mathbb C^2\setminus 0$. Let's prove that $\widetilde X$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb C^2\setminus 0$.

First, we note that $X$ has a finite cover that is diffeomorphic to $S^3\times S^1$. Indeed, take any

$$S^3\subset \widetilde X=\mathbb C^2\setminus 0$$

that encircles $0$. Then, since the action of $\pi_1(X)$ on $\mathbb C^2\setminus X$ is discreet, there exists only finite number of elements $g\in \pi_1(X)$ such that $g\cdot S^3$ intersects $S^3$ in $\mathbb C^2\setminus 0$. Let's take such $g_1\in\pi_1(X)$ that $g_1\cdot S^3$ is disjoint from $S^3$. Let $\mathbb Z=\langle g_1\rangle $ be the group generated by $g_1$. Then it is not hard to see that $(\mathbb C^2\setminus 0)/\langle g_1\rangle$ is diffeomorphic to $S^1\times S^3$. Clearly  $S^1\times S^3$ is a finite cover of $X$.

It remains now to apply the result of Bogomolov that complex surfaces with $b_2=0$ are either Hopf surfaces or Inoue surfaces https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_class_VII . Since $\pi_1(S^1\times S^3)=\mathbb Z$, the complex structure on $S^1\times S^3$ is that of a Hopf surface. We conclude that $\widetilde X$ is byholomorphic to $\mathbb C^2\setminus 0$.

**(i)** As for (i), you can take $(\mathbb C^2\setminus 0)/\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is any finite subgroup of $SU(2)$.

Comment: Instead of using Bogomolov's result, you can use the fact that any complex surface homeomorphic to $S^1\times S^3$ is biholomorphic to a Hopf surface. This was proved by Kodaira in *Complex Structures on $S^1\times S^3$*, Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. U.S.A. 55 (1966), 240–243.

Comment: Thanks Michael for giving this reference! I was not aware of this paper (regretfully)